# Inspiron 7590 - no signal to external display on linux (works on Windows 10)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, intel, external-monitor

I'm using the laptop mantioned above (GTX1650 configuration) and installed a linux distro alongside Windows 10. The only one (but at the same time - the most annoying) problem is no signal to external monitor via HDMI cable (same thing with Intel GPU set as a default and the Nvidia one). The interesting thing here is the fact that when I set the display mode to clone the main display, the external one just turn on and shows cloned screen (with the main screen resolution set - 1080p). The problem occurs when I want to turn off the laptop screen and use the external one only, or use the expand mode.

I've tried a lot of different distros - ubuntu based, fedora, kde neon - no difference. It may be a GPU driver problem I guess, but I've also tried the installation without proprietary drivers - same thing.

Any suggestions?

BTW. All the distros detected the external display properly, i.e. it is visible in both settings app and xrand list.

@EDIT
At this moment I run Ubuntu Budgie 20.04

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a temporary (I hope) workaround for my issue, but it may be not ideal for everyone. As I mentioned before the external display works in CLONE mode, so I use xrand to set the external displays to its defaults:
`xrandr --output <display-name> --rate <rate> --mode <resolution>` (this turns the display on in CLONE mode) and then just turn the laptop screen off `xrandr --output <display-name> --off`.